# How to import Ghidra DB into IDA?

Tags: ida, ghidra

I see many questions about how to import IDA DB into Ghidra but I interesting in the backside. I want to export Ghidra DB and import it into Ida PRO. How I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the `$GHIDRA_ROOT/Extensions/IDAPro/Python/7xx/loaders/xml_loader.py` script for IDA that loads the XML file into IDA.
To create that XML file you need to use the `ghidra.app.util.exporter.XmlExporter` class.